ESP-IDF linker not reporting duplicate functions so generating unsafe binary
I wrote a .c file (not c++) that contains a function called close(). It was public i.e. not static. I realise this was a foolish choice of function name, but assumed the linker would tell me if there was any clash. And indeed in an unrelated part of the code I was using sockets #include "lwip/sockets.h" and calling the close() function that was defined there, and which had completely different arguments.
I built the system with idf.py build and there was no error or warning.
But at runtime it crashed when my sockets code called close() and it was evident from the stack trace that it had called my close() function not the intended one from lwip/sockets.h.
Obviously I can easily fix this now I have seen what it is, but I have lost trust in the linker. Surely it should have given some duplicate symbol warning?! Given that idf.py build seems to compile over 1000 files there is a lot of stuff in the namespace, so an automated check seems essential.
My real concern is that there could be a clash that might not cause a runtime exception, but instead undefined and unwanted behaviour that would be very hard to debug.
On other C platforms (Microchip compilers and several others) I have not encountered such an issue. I think it is because these have all required me to list all the .obj and library files that are to be linked, so the linker can see duplicates. But the ESP-IDF platform only needs me to list my objects and it somehow finds the rest.

LwIP doesn't declare or define any methods named close(s). Instead they use a preprocessor macro to rename this to lwip_close(s): #define close(s)                                  lwip_close(s). So technically there's no function name conflict.

@Tarmo The .h files are a bit convoluted but I see (depending on #ifs) #define lwip_close closesocket and #define closesocket(s) close(s) before declaring int lwip_close(int s);, which I think amounts to declaring int close(int s);. But however it happens, the runtime trace showed that it is calling the wrong close(s).

Ah, OK. I'll defer to tofro-s answer then. The GNU linker is a lazy thing (for speed, I assume) and I've been bitten by it before. You can tell it to do an exhaustive search with the --start-group and --end-group options if you can accept the performance penalty - maybe it helps with this issue as well. Anyway, that's why C++ has namespaces :)

You need to understand a bit better what a linker does (absolutely nothing is wrong with yours, it does exactly what it should.)

Collect all symbols from all object files (and the C startup).
Resolve the symbols between the object files
All symbols still unresolved at this point, try and resolve them from given libraries.

i.e. the linker will, at the end of the object link phase, only start looking for symbols that are not yet resolved, and use libraries for those. In your case, the request for close() could be satisfied from object files which are handled with precedence, and the linker didn't even search for close() in the libraries. So, in short: The linker only takes what it needs from libraries. This is to ensure that the absolute minimum of object files contained in libraries is included in the resulting binary.
The order in which free-standing objects and objects in libraries are pulled in typically depends on the order the objects show up in the command line. By changing the order of objects and libraries, you can possibly make the linker warn you of such occurrences - but you should know that you should only try and override system functions if you know what you're doing.

That would explain the behaviour I am seeing. But it does seem unsafe. It is going to create a binary with undefined behaviour if I happen to re-use any symbol name that is already used in any of the ESP-IDF library of > 1000 files. How can you possibly have certainty that there's no name clash?

Well for close() we can hopefully agree that this is a pretty well-known Posix function and thus a very unfortunate (this is a deliberately mild choice of attribute) choice of names. Could you have made your close () static? If yes, why didn't you? Could you have made your choice of names more meaningful by, for example including what's being closed in the naming? If yes, why didn't you? You can ask the linker for a cross-reference file and check which symbol was resolved from what object. The GNU linker can be made to pull in a complete library (with "--whole-archive") ...

... with all its symbols - which would have led to an error message about multiple definitions in your case (and, at the same time, exploding your binary size).

As I said in the question I was foolish to write a non static close(). It was initial test code and easily fixed. The question was about how I can regain trust in Espressif's otherwise excellent looking idf.py build. I thought there was a safety net and I am slightly alarmed that there isn't one. I was hoping I could add something the the CMakeLists.txt in my project folder that would ensure it would generate a safe binary.

Note that ESP-IDF also leverages this behavior to "exclude" some parts of the code. E.g., some code related to C++ exceptions is not included in the binary if C++ exceptions are disabled in menuconfig. This is done by defining the same functions, which just quickly call abort(), in an object file that is linked in before libsupc++ is linked in. This roughly saves about 3-6K of code size, depending on the architecture.
